# What is a word for someone that only does something to benefit them?

Tags: single-word-requests

Take this paragraph for example: I am a follower, not a leader. Hell, I'm not even that good of a follower either, just someone who will do your bidding for the right price. Even then, if it doesn't benefit me -- or put you in debt to me -- I won't do it.

Comment: Do you need a fancy word for selfish,, or self-centered?

Comment: I not too sure yet. Perhaps both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Self-serving** - [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-serving)

> Having or showing concern only about your own needs and interests.

There are a TON of synonyms for selfish, pick yours: [Thesaurus selfish](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/selfish). In my opinion, **self-serving** fits quite perfectly into your description.

Answer (score 5):

**Mercenary** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mercenary)

> *noun* 1.1 A person primarily motivated by personal gain
>   *"cricket’s most infamous mercenary"*

Answer (score 1):

In the case of your example paragraph:

> I am a follower, not a leader. Hell, I'm not even that good of a
> follower either, just someone who will do your bidding for the right
> price. Even then, if it doesn't benefit me -- or put you in debt to me
> -- I won't do it.

## [Moneygrabber](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/moneygrabbing)

Fits well, which is a countable noun derived from:

[Moneygrabbing](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/moneygrabbing)

> Very interested in money and trying to get as much money as possible. - Macmillan