# Is there a word for someone who does favors for others because they want something in return?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I know there's a certain word for it in an actual English dictionary that I seem to have forgotten. But what is a person called when they do favors for people only because they want something in return?

Comment: Can you give us a context for the word? A situation in which it may be used?

Comment: Bootlicker, suck-up.

Comment: Venal, having self-interest ... you can look antonyms for 'altruism' to see if any provide a closer match.

Comment: Such a person is *manipulative*.

Comment: Closely related: [What is a word for someone that only does something to benefit them?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/333025/what-is-a-word-for-someone-that-only-does-something-to-benefit-them)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sound more formal, you could say that someone is looking for a **quid pro quo**:

> #### Quid Pro Quo
>
> 1. something that is given to you or done for you in return for something you have given to or done for someone else.
>    *in politics nobody does something for nothing: there's always a quid pro quo involved*

([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quid%20pro%20quo))

A less formal alternative is *tit for tat*:

> **noun**
>
> 1. with an equivalent given in retaliation, as a blow for a blow, reparteé, etc.:
>    *He answered their insults tit for tat.*

([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tit-for-tat?s=t))

Comment: Or the less dignified version, _tit for tat_.

Comment: @DougWarren Would you mind if I put that into my answer, since it is effectively the same as this answer?

Comment: I certainly don't mind.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for a "name" for that person, aren't you?

How about calling him/her a [sycophant](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sycophant)?

> A person who acts obsequiously towards someone important in order to
> gain advantage.

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sycophant) puts it a bit more bluntly:

> a servile self-seeking flatterer

---

*[Note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sycophant)* that this was not the original meaning of the word.

Also *note* that this word is to be used chiefly in cases where the person doing the favor(s) is in a somewhat *inferior* position (in relation to, say, you).

Answer (score 1):

You could say that the person has an ***Ulterior Motive***:

> #### Ulterior Motive
>
> - If you say that someone has an ulterior motive for doing something, you believe that they have a hidden reason for doing it

([Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ulterior-motive))

Comment: This makes them seem *very* sinister.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I don't think *ulterior motive* has a sinister connotation. It just has a selfish one.

Comment: Well, you do it to get an advantage *over* someone, potentially for a concealed reason (according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ulterior_motive)) It's not a bad answer, I just think that you should include it as a caveat.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I don't like to go off Wikipedia definitions. An Ulterior motive is usually *secretive*, but it doesn't mean that it's always sinister, although it can be. ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ulterior%20motive)) The OP doesn't specify only positive references. The OP kinda seems like it wants to describe a semi-sinister person.

Comment: I don't have a noun, but if you want a verb that's bit more genteel than "sucking up," if you curry favor you seek to "advance yourself through flattery or fawning." (Random House College Dictionary)

Comment: BTW the origin of "curry favor" has nothing to do with flavor or favor, but it's fun.

Answer (score 1):

I would describe someone like that as *mercenary*: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mercenary

adjective
1.
working or acting merely for money or other reward; venal.

The synonym *altruistic* in this link is pretty much the exact opposite of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

*I'll scratch your back if you'll scratch mine* would indicate the measure of reciprocity that the OP alludes to in the stated interactions between two people.

**I'll scratch your back if you'll scratch mine:**

*Idiom* -- "You do a favor for me and I'll do a favor for you; if you do something for me that I cannot do for myself, I will do something for you that you cannot do for yourself". (The Free Dictionary)

Comment: And so one might call them *symbiotic*, but that's a bit arcane, and some dictionaries define it as a hypernym of *parasitic*.